# Android Accelerometer Sensor - How to identify is device is on flat surface

Tags: android, android-sensors

Im trying to identify is device horizontally stable on surface. Please check attachment for more clear understanding . [Click Here](https://media.giphy.com/media/v1.Y2lkPTc5MGI3NjExOTJmYzlkZTA0MTg4OTBlNjkxMjA3OTg0Mzc0ZTMxMGQ5MTRkMjA5MCZjdD1n/r4jkyrxZtQrJDNoOV2/giphy.gif)

I have tried uses of Accelerometer and MagneticField sensors and tried to rotate the line but it's not working

```
Image(
                        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_horizontal_line),
                        colorFilter = ColorFilter.tint(color = colorResource(id = R.color.white)),
                        contentDescription = null,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .graphicsLayer {
                                rotationZ = accelerometerSensorState.zForce
                            },
                    )
```

Here zForce is nothing but 3rd value of onSensorChanged method

Answer (score 0):

Use the gravity sensor.  It will tell you the magnitude of the force of gravity along the x, y, and z axes.  If you then want to know the angle of the phone relative to straight up and down, you can use some basic trigonometry.  Remember that if it you're holding the phone in portait and perfectly straight up, the gravity vector would be 100% in the direction of y.

Comment: Thanks Gabe Sechan for answer. It will be great if you provide some code